# Filter FeatureCollection by list of dates to new several FeatureCollections for each date

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, feature-collection

I have a FeatureCollection of Features (zonstats_reduced) that I obtained after Reduce Regions based on Sentinel mosaics. I have created daily Sentinel mosaics for the years 2017-2019. Each feature has the statistics and date (img:id) in properties which were copied from the Sentinel data earlier. I would like to create a separate FeatureCollection for each date (one day=one FeatureCollection), but my FeatureCollections are empty despite filtering by the created list of daily mosaic dates.

```
var imlist1 = s2index.toList(s2index.size());
var uni_dates = imlist1.map(function(d){
    return ee.Image(d).date().format("YYYY-MM-dd");
}).distinct();
print('list of features for each date', uni_dates);

var new_colls = uni_dates.map(function(n){
  var coll =  zonstats_reduced.filter(ee.Filter.eq('img:id', ee.String(ee.Number(n))));
  return ee.FeatureCollection(coll);
});
print(new_colls);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are most likely not empty, they're just not recursively expanded in the print.  Try printing the size of one explicitly.

```
print(ee.FeatureCollection(new_colls.get(0)).size())
```

By the way, your dates are not numbers, they're strings, so the ee.Number inside the last map isn't correct (you don't need the ee.String cast either).  It doesn't seem to be hurting anything, but it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you Noel, you're right, they are not empty. Your answer helped me.